# How to manipulate list variable in Jinja2 template?

Tags: ansible

I've created a role which stores the unreachable hosts in a variable:

```yaml
- block:
  - set_fact:
      unreachable_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|difference(ansible_play_hosts) }}"
  - debug:
      var: unreachable_hosts
  run_once: true
```

Depending on the amount of unreachable hosts this returns something like this:

```json
"unreachable_hosts": [
    "server001",
    "server003"
]
```

In another role I'm creating an HTML file with Jinja2 template. In that HTML file I'd like to list all unreachable hosts per line (in a table row). I tried to make a for-loop in my HTML code like this:

```html
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <b> Unreachable Servers: </b> <br>
          <ul>
          {% for items in unreachable_hosts %}
            <li font color="red">{{ unreachable_hosts }} </li>
            {% endfor %}
         </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

But this creates an output like this:

```
Unreachable Servers:

- ['server001', 'server003']
- ['server001', 'server003']
```

I'd like to manipulate the output to look like this:

```
Unreachable Servers:

- server001
- server003
```

Comment: Shouldn't `{{ unreachable_hosts }}` be `{{ items }}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, `items` is an item in the `unreachable_hosts` list. To output one of the items being iterated over:

```
{% for items in unreachable_hosts %}
  <li font color="red">{{ items }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

(I would also rename `items` to `item` (singular) since it contains a single item.)